# how to strip alt character code with php

Tags: php, string, character, strip

I'm using this code to strip unwanted characters from a string, but I have a big problem with ALT+0160 character which is a non break space. I need to remove it as well

```
    $name = str_replace ("'", "", $name);

    $name = str_replace ("&quot;", '"', $name);

    $name = str_replace ("&amp;", "&", $name);

    $name = str_replace ("&lt;", "", $name);

    $name = str_replace ("&gt;", "", $name);

    $name = str_replace ("&", "_", $name);

    $name = str_replace ("*", "_", $name);

    $name = preg_replace('/[^ \p{L}\p{N} \@ \_ \- \.]/u', '', $name);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$name=str_replace(chr(0xc2a0),'',$name);
```

Comment: yes but when i use "" it doesnt work but when i used "_" it worked
thanks again